# How to fetch objects of array one by one with for loop in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, for-loop

I've written for loop to fetch objects from array one by one, but the result fetched all of objects from loop and repeated those in one string.

Here is my code:

```
state = {
    b: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
}

b = () => {
    let d = [];
    for (var i =0; i<=this.state.b.length - 1; i++) {
        d.push(this.state.b[i])
    }
    return d;
};
```

I'm beginner in react native, how can I change this code to show object arrays like  a list

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListView` directly like this :

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.b}
    renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
/>
```

Comment: I got this error listview has been removed from react native

Comment: try `FlatList` inplace